# Unmarshal method for complex object with go reflections

Tags: go, reflection

I'm starting to writing more complex go code, and my object node it to convert a list from a JSON object to a map with a particular key. This operation helps me to speed up my algorithm. But I have a problem now,  my container struct has several complex JSON and I'm not able to write a generic solution to achieve a generic solution. The only way that I have in mind is to use a big switch case, but I think this is not the right solution.

This is my code at the moment, where the `statusChannel` is a map in the code but it is a list in the JSON string

```
type MetricOne struct {
    // Internal id to identify the metric
    id int `json:"-"`
    // Version of metrics format, it is used to migrate the
    // JSON payload from previous version of plugin.
    Version int `json:"version"`
    // Name of the metrics
    Name   string  `json:"metric_name"`
    NodeId string  `json:"node_id"`
    Color  string  `json:"color"`
    OSInfo *osInfo `json:"os_info"`
    // timezone where the node is located
    Timezone string `json:"timezone"`
    // array of the up_time
    UpTime []*status `json:"up_time"`
    // map of informatonof channel information
    ChannelsInfo map[string]*statusChannel `json:"channels_info"`
}

func (instance *MetricOne) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    jsonMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    reflectType := reflect.TypeOf(*instance)
    reflectValue := reflect.ValueOf(*instance)
    nFiled := reflectValue.Type().NumField()

    for i := 0; i < nFiled; i++ {
        key := reflectType.Field(i)
        valueFiled := reflectValue.Field(i)
        jsonName := key.Tag.Get("json")
        switch jsonName {
        case "-":
            // skip
            continue
        case "channels_info":
            // TODO convert the map[string]*statusChannel in a list of statusChannel
            statusChannels := make([]*statusChannel, 0)
            for _, value := range valueFiled.Interface().(map[string]*statusChannel) {
                statusChannels = append(statusChannels, value)
            }
            jsonMap[jsonName] = statusChannels
        default:
            jsonMap[jsonName] = valueFiled.Interface()
        }
    }

    return json.Marshal(jsonMap)
}

func (instance *MetricOne) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var jsonMap map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &jsonMap)
    if err != nil {
        log.GetInstance().Error(fmt.Sprintf("Error: %s", err))
        return err
    }
    instance.Migrate(jsonMap)
    reflectValue := reflect.ValueOf(instance)
    reflectStruct := reflectValue.Elem()
    // reflectType := reflectValue.Type()
    for key, value := range jsonMap {
        fieldName, err := utils.GetFieldName(key, "json", *instance)
        if err != nil {
            log.GetInstance().Info(fmt.Sprintf("Error: %s", err))
            if strings.Contains(key, "dev_") {
                log.GetInstance().Info("dev propriety skipped if missed")
                continue
            }
            return err
        }
        field := reflectStruct.FieldByName(*fieldName)
        fieldType := field.Type()
        filedValue := field.Interface()
        val := reflect.ValueOf(filedValue)

        switch key {
        case "channels_info":
            statusChannelsMap := make(map[string]*statusChannel)
            toArray := value.([]interface{})
            for _, status := range toArray {
                var statusType statusChannel
                jsonVal, err := json.Marshal(status)
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
                err = json.Unmarshal(jsonVal, &statusType)
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
                statusChannelsMap[statusType.ChannelId] = &statusType
            }
            field.Set(reflect.ValueOf(statusChannelsMap))
        default:
            field.Set(val.Convert(fieldType))
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

And when I will decode the object I receive the following error:

```
➜  go-metrics-reported git:(dev) ✗ make check
go test -v ./...
?       github.com/OpenLNMetrics/go-metrics-reported/cmd/go-metrics-reported    [no test files]
?       github.com/OpenLNMetrics/go-metrics-reported/init/persistence   [no test files]
=== RUN   TestJSONSerializzation
--- PASS: TestJSONSerializzation (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestJSONDeserializzation
--- FAIL: TestJSONDeserializzation (0.00s)
panic: reflect.Value.Convert: value of type map[string]interface {} cannot be converted to type *plugin.osInfo [recovered]
    panic: reflect.Value.Convert: value of type map[string]interface {} cannot be converted to type *plugin.osInfo

goroutine 7 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1.1(0x61b440, 0xc0001d69a0)
    /home/vincent/.gosdk/go/src/testing/testing.go:1072 +0x30d
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc000001e00)
    /home/vincent/.gosdk/go/src/testing/testing.go:1075 +0x41a
panic(0x61b440, 0xc0001d69a0)
    /home/vincent/.gosdk/go/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x1b9
reflect.Value.Convert(0x6283e0, 0xc0001bb1a0, 0x15, 0x6b93a0, 0x610dc0, 0x610dc0, 0xc00014cb40, 0x196)
    /home/vincent/.gosdk/go/src/reflect/value.go:2447 +0x229
github.com/OpenLNMetrics/go-metrics-reported/internal/plugin.(*MetricOne).UnmarshalJSON(0xc00014cb00, 0xc0001d8000, 0x493, 0x500, 0x7f04d01453d8, 0xc00014cb00)
    /home/vincent/Github/OpenLNMetrics/go-metrics-reported/internal/plugin/metrics_one.go:204 +0x5b3
encoding/json.(*decodeState).object(0xc00010be40, 0x657160, 0xc00014cb00, 0x16, 0xc00010be68, 0x7b)
    /home/vincent/.gosdk/go/src/encoding/json/decode.go:609 +0x207c
encoding/json.(*decodeState).value(0xc00010be40, 0x657160, 0xc00014cb00, 0x16, 0xc000034698, 0x54ec19)
    /home/vincent/.gosdk/go/src/encoding/json/decode.go:370 +0x6d
encoding/json.(*decodeState).unmarshal(0xc00010be40, 0x657160, 0xc00014cb00, 0xc00010be68, 0x0)
    /home/vincent/.gosdk/go/src/encoding/json/decode.go:180 +0x1ea
encoding/json.Unmarshal(0xc0001d8000, 0x493, 0x500, 0x657160, 0xc00014cb00, 0x500, 0x48cba6)
    /home/vincent/.gosdk/go/src/encoding/json/decode.go:107 +0x112
github.com/OpenLNMetrics/go-metrics-reported/internal/plugin.TestJSONDeserializzation(0xc000001e00)
    /home/vincent/Github/OpenLNMetrics/go-metrics-reported/internal/plugin/metric_one_test.go:87 +0x95
testing.tRunner(0xc000001e00, 0x681000)
    /home/vincent/.gosdk/go/src/testing/testing.go:1123 +0xef
created by testing.(*T).Run
    /home/vincent/.gosdk/go/src/testing/testing.go:1168 +0x2b3
FAIL    github.com/OpenLNMetrics/go-metrics-reported/internal/plugin    0.008s
?       github.com/OpenLNMetrics/go-metrics-reported/pkg/db [no test files]
?       github.com/OpenLNMetrics/go-metrics-reported/pkg/graphql    [no test files]
?       github.com/OpenLNMetrics/go-metrics-reported/pkg/log    [no test files]
?       github.com/OpenLNMetrics/go-metrics-reported/pkg/utils  [no test files]
FAIL
make: *** [Makefile:15: check] Error 1
```

can someone explain how I can do this operation in a generic way?

Comment: Why are you using reflection for this?

Comment: @mkopriva because It is the only solution that I know to get the field from json payload and muve it in a Map. I don't know the answer to your question. Why I did it? Because it is the only method that I know.

Comment: Apologies, the previous solution had a recursive-call issue, try this one: https://play.golang.org/p/ZF8qG3YjL11

Comment: @mkopriva that is what I'm looking for, but can you explain all that you do in an answer? it is an easy to copy and past your code and make it workable, but I want to understand the difference with mine and what is the best practice in go in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/jzU_lHj1wk7

```golang
type MetricOne struct {
    // ...

    // Have this field be ignored.
    ChannelsInfo map[string]*statusChannel `json:"-"`
}
```

```golang
func (m MetricOne) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // Declare a new type using the definition of MetricOne,
    // the result of this is that M will have the same structure
    // as MetricOne but none of its methods (this avoids recursive
    // calls to MarshalJSON).
    //
    // Also because M and MetricOne have the same structure you can
    // easily convert between those two. e.g. M(MetricOne{}) and
    // MetricOne(M{}) are valid expressions.
    type M MetricOne

    // Declare a new type that has a field of the "desired" type and
    // also **embeds** the M type. Embedding promotes M's fields to T
    // and encoding/json will marshal those fields unnested/flattened, 
    // i.e. at the same level as the channels_info field.
    type T struct {
        M
        ChannelsInfo []*statusChannel `json:"channels_info"`
    }

    // move map elements to slice
    channels := make([]*statusChannel, 0, len(m.ChannelsInfo))
    for _, c := range m.ChannelsInfo {
        channels = append(channels, c)
    }

    // Pass in an instance of the new type T to json.Marshal.
    // For the embedded M field use a converted instance of the receiver.
    // For the ChannelsInfo field use the channels slice.
    return json.Marshal(T{
        M:            M(m),
        ChannelsInfo: channels,
    })
}
```

```golang
// Same as MarshalJSON but in reverse.
func (m *MetricOne) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type M MetricOne
    type T struct {
        *M
        ChannelsInfo []*statusChannel `json:"channels_info"`
    }
    t := T{M: (*M)(m)}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &t); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    m.ChannelsInfo = make(map[string]*statusChannel, len(t.ChannelsInfo))
    for _, c := range t.ChannelsInfo {
        m.ChannelsInfo[c.ChannelId] = c
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Well your answer is very well done, thanks you to make this effort and make go lang accessible for new people